# How to plot a list of torch.tensors? "RuntimeError: Can't call numpy() on Tensor that requires grad. Use tensor.detach().numpy() instead."

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, pytorch, tensor

I am learning Pytorch and was following a tutorial when I came accross this error:
*"RuntimeError: Can't call numpy() on Tensor that requires grad. Use tensor.detach().numpy() instead."*

I am adding my losses to a list called *final_losses*

```
for i in range(epochs):
    y_pred=model.forward(X_train)
    loss=loss_function(y_pred,y_train)
    final_losses.append(loss)
```

This is a simple ANN module having 2 fully connected layers and I use Relu function in them.
I am trying to print a graph of epochs vs loss:

```
plt.plot(range(epochs),final_losses)
plt.show()
```

When I execute this I am getting the above error.(**"RuntimeError: Can't call numpy() on Tensor that requires grad. Use tensor.detach().numpy() instead."**)

I have printed the these variables for your reference:

**Epochs is 150, length of final_losses is 150  and final_losses is [tensor(1.5851, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward0),...**

I also tried doing this :

```
plt.plot(range(epochs),torch.detach(final_losses).numpy())
plt.show()
```

I am getting the following error:
*TypeError: detach(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not list*

Please let me know how to solve this.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a list of tensors, rather than a tensor. Modify your initial code to store your losses as numpy arrays (or singular floats by taking the mean):

```
for i in range(epochs):
    y_pred=model.forward(X_train)
    loss=loss_function(y_pred,y_train)
    final_losses.append(loss.detach().numpy())
```

If you are on gpu you might also need to convert to cpu in that last line.